# Decrypting using openssl c/c++ API fails

Tags: c++, openssl

I create a file using openssl from the commandline. Let's say:

> echo 'foobar' | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -pass pass:testing >
>   sample

I can decrypt this doing

> cat sample | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -pass pass:testing

That works fine.

Now I want to decrypt that file using the openssl c/c++ API but I can't get this quite right. I am trying to decrypt like so

```
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>

using EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr = std::unique_ptr<EVP_CIPHER_CTX, decltype(&::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free)>;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    ERR_load_crypto_strings();

    EVP_add_cipher(EVP_aes_128_cbc());

    std::string l_key{"testing"};
    std::string l_ctext{};

    std::ifstream l_file("sample", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);

    if(l_file.is_open())
    {
      std::streampos l_size = l_file.tellg();
      char * lp_buffer = new char[l_size];

      l_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
      l_file.read(lp_buffer, l_size);
      l_ctext.append(lp_buffer, l_size);  

      delete lp_buffer;
      l_file.close();
    }

    std::string l_rtext;

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free_ptr ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new(), ::EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free);

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx.get(), EVP_aes_128_cbc(), NULL,
                               (const unsigned char*)l_key.c_str(), NULL));
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);

    int l_len;

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx.get(), (unsigned char*)&l_rtext[0], &l_len,
                              (const unsigned char*)l_ctext.data(),
                              l_ctext.size()))
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);

    if(1 != EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx.get(), (unsigned char*)&l_rtext[0] + l_len,
                                &l_len))
      ERR_print_errors_fp(stdout);

    ERR_free_strings();

    exit(0);
}
```

However that last call to `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` fails with

```
140559955420968:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:596:
```

Most of this code is based on the examples that come with the openssl API. What am I doing wrong? I set the IV to NULL in `EVP_DecryptInit_ex` because as far as I found out, this is acceptable as long as I don't use the key multiple times.

All this on a Fedora machine with GCC

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed this earlier... *"I set the IV to NULL... "* - CBC mode requires an IV. You can't set it to NULL. Also, you need to `size` or `resize` your `l_rtext`. The recovered text will be at most `l_size` in size. Once `EVP_DecryptFinal_ex` you should call `resize` to set the final size of the buffer.

Comment: I can encrypt something without an IV if I use the API. The above code will decrypt that fine. As I wrote in my answer - the problem I discovered is that 'openssl enc' from the commandline will use a default salt and it will always use an IV.

Comment: *"I can encrypt something without an IV if I use the API..."* - if that is true, then it sounds like a bug to me. OpenSSL cannot proceed in CBC mode (and other modes except ECB) without an IV.

Answer (score 1):

I kind of figured out what I did wrong.

- The commandline 'openssl enc' command uses a default salt, my code above didn't look for that. So (rather than try to work with the '-nosalt' option) I remove the first 16 bytes from the encrypted string and use the last 8 of that as the salt.
- I was feeding the password to the EVP methods as a 'key'. It seems 'openssl enc' doesn't do this so one needs to use the salt and the password to create a key and IV (rather than using NULL which is what I did).
- There was an error in the above code in that l_rtext needs a resize() to reflect the fact that characters were added to it.